# Raspberry Pi 4B 8 Flashes on ACT Light

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B which was working for a while, when one day it flashed 8 times on the green ACT Light and nothing was displayed. I know that 8 flashes means broken bootcode.bin or something, but can someone give me a step by step process to fix this? I have already tried re-installing the OS.

Comment: Have you tried another SD card?

Comment: `I know that 8 flashes means broken bootcode.bin` - no, that's on pi's other than the pi 4 ... the pi 4 flashes 8 times for *SDRAM failure* - which would appear to be a terminal condition I'm afraid - though, perhaps you could try recovery flashing the EEPROM - https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#eeprom-update-files